# Rails 4 named scope with record always at end

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to order records alphabetically, excluding one record, which I want at the end?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope -> { order(:name) }

end
```

I always want the category named 'Other' to be at the end.

Comment: add a sort field to category and handle then exceptions

Comment: This may be the right solution, however, I have multiple models in which this applies. Is there a way to extract this into a concern or will this require an additional field on each of these models?

Comment: i usually add a new field with default value and then i make some entries with 9999 or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky. In SQL you can [add `CASE` statements to your `ORDER BY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862578/custom-sorting-in-sql-order-by-clause). In your case the SQL would be something similar to.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY
    (
     CASE
       WHEN name = 'Other' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
     END
    )
```

Here's a [live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a4dc/1).

As far as I know, the ActiveRecord `order` method accepts arbitrary string, so you *could* (not tested) be able to pass the case to the method

```
Category.order("CASE WHEN name = 'Other' ... ")
```

This approach seems complicated, but if you can get it to work is by far the most efficient.

The second alternative is to play a little bit with ActiveRecord.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.ordered(condition = nil)
    # Get the ID of the record to exclude
    excluded = self.where(name: 'Other').pluck(:id).first
    # order the records and collect the ids
    ids =  where('id <> ?', excluded).order(condition).pluck(:id) 
    # append the excluded at the end
    ids << excluded

    # recreate the scope and return it.
    where(id: ids)
  end

end

Category.where(...).ordered
```

Generally speaking, I encourage you to avoid `default_scopes` in ActiveRecord. It's so easy to add them, but very hard to remove them when you need.

Comment: Would you suggest having a named scope for this instance?

Comment: Yes. In fact, `self.ordered` is a named scope. (you can create named scopes with `scope :foo, -> { ... }` or as methods with `def self.foo`

Comment: Thanks. That works well and seems to be most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below ActiveRecord query

```
Category.order("CASE WHEN name = 'Other' then 0 else 1 END DESC, name ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just to add an additional field "position" and sort everything by it. Or you can order by 2 fields (position, name). All Categories will have position equal = 0, and "Other" equal to 999 for example