# Special sorting for MySQL result

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to get `MySQL` to put a row which matches some condition on the first position?

For instance, say that my result is [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1987] and I want it to become [6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1987] (I want the number 6 to be on the first position)

Comment: position of the row or column?

Comment: the row that I want it to be on the first place is in the middle, so changing the order won't do it

Comment: You must use an other parameter to sort your result. Sorting results with ID isn't a good idea.

Comment: actually it is not a matter of sorting, I have one very specific condition which matches with only one row and I want that row to be on the first place

Comment: The only solution (php solution) I'm seeing right now would be to perform two mysql requests, one of them would exclude the row, and the other would include only the row and in the end I would merge the two results

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Sorting in SQL order by clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862578/custom-sorting-in-sql-order-by-clause)

Comment: The FIELD() function was made for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you are searching for this

```
SELECT * FROM `pctable`order by colName=6 desc, colName
```

so colName = 6 will be in top and then for others it will be id wise sort.

Comment: Looks like it's the solution, I'm going to try it on Doctrine ORM. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CASE` expression in your `Order by` clause. Such as

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COL_VALUE = 'xxx' THEN '1'
              WHEN COL_VALUE = 'xxx' THEN '2'              
              ELSE COL_VALUE END ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with IF in the SELECT somehow:

```
SELECT IF(number = 6, number, ''), number FROM colname
```